# Are convolutional layers necessary for Deep Q Networks?

Tags: machine-learning, reinforcement-learning

I'm currently trying to build a deep Q network to play the classic Snake game. I designed the game in such a way that the state space is confined to a 20 x 20 matrix, with 1's representing a square occupied by a body, 2 representing a square occupied by the head, and 5 representing a square occupied by food. Given the fact that the space is relatively small, would it be feasible to have the network input be a 400 dimensional vector instead of a raw image?

Answer (score 0):

You could try a 400-dimensional vector and look at the performance of the agent(learning). If it doesn't improve, then you should try a CNN. But in my opinion, a 400-dimensional vector should work.

Also, make sure that you normalise the state inputs to [0,1] or [-1,1] before feeding it to the neural network.

Comment: Thanks for the response. By normalizing the state input, you mean each of the elements in the vector, correct?

Comment: By normalising I do mean dividing all the elements of the input vector by 5 as your maximum pixel value is 5.